# $ \dot{\phi}(t)=-\omega(\phi(t)) \nabla F(\phi(t)), \ \phi(0)=x$. Prove that the solution of the IVP can be defined on $[0,+\infty)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, gradient-flows

> Assume $F\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$, for each initial value $x$, consider the IVP:
> $$
> \dot{\phi}(t)=-\omega(\phi(t)) \nabla F(\phi(t)), \ \phi(0)=x,
> $$where $\omega(y)=\dfrac{|\nabla F(y)|}{1+|\nabla F(y)|^2}$.
> Prove that the solution of the IVP can be defined on $[0,+\infty)$.

I am currectly learning mountain pass theorem and the textbook use the proposition above without proof. I have some diffculty in solving the problem by the extensibility theorem. The $\omega$ is complicated so I  only want to use its boundness. Is my thoughts ok and how to go on? If not, please suggest your method.

Any hint or complete proof can be very helpful!

Comment: I believe this should follow from the blowup criterion for ODE; the right hand side is uniformly bounded and thus $\dot\phi$ cannot go to infinity so neither can $\phi$ (in finite time).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is $t_0$ such that
$$\lim_{t\to t_0^-}|\phi(t)|=\infty. \tag1$$
Integrating the equation from $0$ to $t$ ($t<t_0$) gives
$$ \phi(t)-x=-\int_0^t\omega(\phi(s)) \nabla F(\phi(s))\mathrm{d}s. $$
So
$$ |\phi(t)|\le |x|+\int_0^t\omega(\phi(s)) |\nabla F(\phi(s))|\mathrm{d}s=|x|+\int_0^t\dfrac{|\nabla F(\phi(s))|^2}{1+|\nabla F(\phi(s)|^2}ds\le|x|+t. \tag{2} $$
Letting $t\to t_0^-$ in (2) will be against (2). So the solution $\phi(t)$ is well defined in $[0,\infty)$.